# How to save firmware file selected from document picker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, swift5, userdefaults

I am trying to upgrade the radar using a firmware file. I am selecting a firmware file using a document picker and saving its path to a singleton class variable. But the problem is when I go to the background and return it shows that the file does not exist in that path. How can I resolve the issue? The code for saving the path is
`

```
    let file = urls[0]
    do {
         let filePath = file.path

         self.firmwareLocalfilePath = filePath

         SessionController.sharedController.filePath = self.firmwareLocalfilePath
```

'

Here SessionController.sharedController.filePath is my singleton variable. The condition to check file availability is

`if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: self.firmwareLocalfilePath!)`

When I go to the background and come back it is getting that
"File does not exist [/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92D35520-C1E8-44DD-960E-B7024E8602E8/tmp/com.houston-radar.app-Inbox/dc300b04_v297.frm]"

There are lots of other kinds of stuff there that's why I am not uploading the full code. The code is related to the file I wrote here. How can I resolve this issue? Can I save the file somewhere like userdefault. I googled it a lot but did not get any solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just a guess... That path looks like a temporary path. When you get the path, can you move the file to a permanent location and then save that permanent path?

Comment: Your file appears to have ended up in the `tmp` directory, which is a _temporary_ directory. Try storing it elsewhere, that might solve your problem

Comment: Hi @stewart Macdonald I used 
'FileManager.default.moveItem(at:URL(string:  self.firmwareLocalfilePath!)!, to: <#T##URL#>)'
 to save it , What can I give in the place of to ?

Comment: @Bram did you mean a variable?

Comment: @JoiceGeorge no, I mean the file itself, the path. You can try to store the file in the `Application Support` directory. You might be able to find it using `FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first`

Comment: @Bram I tried with '       
do {
           let applicationSupportDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
           let demoPlistURL = applicationSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent(SessionController.sharedController.filePath!)
           SessionController.sharedController.filePath = demoPlistURL.path
           print("url is joice", demoPlistURL.path)
       } catch {
           print(error)
       } 
'  but got same result file does not exist

Comment: That's not how it works. The file you load into memory is currently written to the `/tmp` folder, which, again, is a _temporary_ folder. Files in this folder will be removed whenever the OS feels like removing it. You either have to save the file to any other folder but a temporary or cache folder when you load it, or move it out of the temporary folder as soon as possible. I've provided you an example folder where you can store it. Simply adding the filePath you have to there is not enough, you still have to move the file properly

Comment: @Bram https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/78189 is that way to save the file? If it is not can you provide me with the code? Very sorry to ask you since I am very new to swift

Comment: @StewartMacdonald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is loaded/stored in a *temporary* directory. iOS itself decides when it wants to remove files from that directory. It appears you're currently experiencing it while going to the background. I would recommend trying to initially save it in a non temporary directory, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Therefore, you could try to move it from the temporary folder to a non temporary folder, such as the `Application Support` folder.

```swift
do {
    // 1. Get the firmware URL at which the firmware file is located 
    //    (your current temporary URL)
    let firmwarePath: URL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: localFilePath)

    // 2. Create a persistent URL
    let newFirmwarePath = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(firmwarePath.lastPathComponent)

    // 3. Try moving the file from the temporary directory to a non temporary directory
    //.   This is where we move it from the /tmp to /Application Support
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: firmwarePath, to: newFirmwarePath)

    // 4. Lastly, update your static property
    SessionController.sharedController.filePath = newFirmwarePath.path
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I feel like storing the path this way is very error prone, so I can only recommend trying to figure out an alternative way to communicate the file/path/location. But I suppose this should work

Comment: @JoiceGeorge Glad to hear that. Keep in mind, the files are now persistent, you might want to cleanup the Application Support directory every so often